# How to use the squeeze theorem to show that $a_n→ 0$ as $n →∞ $ for the sequence $a_n :=1/n(1 + n.cos^6(n^{2017} − 3√(5n))$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Use the squeeze theorem to show that $a_n→ 0$ as $n →∞ $ for the sequence $a_n :=1/n(1 + n.cos^6(n^{2017} − 3√(5n))$.

What i did so far was i just try to use the fact that $0≤cos^6(t)≤1$ but i don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1{n^2+n}=\frac1{n(1+n)}\le\frac1{n\left(1+n\cos^6\left(n^{2017}-3\sqrt{5n}\right)\right)}\le\frac1{n}$$

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks, corrected. The basic idea remains.

Comment: The $(1+ n\cos^6  \dots )$ is upstairs isn't it?

Comment: @zhw. I'm not sure what you mean with upstairs, but int general $$1\le1+n\cos^6(...)\le1+n$$

Comment: True, but as the problem is stated, that doesn't help.

Comment: @zhw. I think it does. Can you spot any mistake in what I did? If there's one I'll be glad to correct it, otherwise a straightforward use of the squeeze theorem solves the problem at once.

Comment: But what I see is $$a_n :=\dfrac{1}{n}\left(1 + n\cdot\cos^6\left(n^{2017} − 3\sqrt{5n}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @zhw. I see it in the denominator and the OP hasn't said half a thing. In the body of the question is the expression you wrote **but that is something someone else edited**...

Comment: I rolled back that edit in the question. In case the OP wants to edit his question he can do it.